# Generating an Array based on a total Count and split Number

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to generate an array like below using dataweave with two dynamic input i.e totalCount=1000 and splitNumber=100 in mule . I am able to do the same in Java script but not sure how to achieve this in dataweave.

```
{ start: 1, end: 100 },
{ start: 101, end: 200 },
{ start: 201, end: 300 },
{ start: 301, end: 400 },
{ start: 401, end: 500 },
{ start: 501, end: 600 },
{ start: 601, end: 700 },
{ start: 701, end: 800 },
{ start: 801, end: 900 },
{ start: 901, end: 1000 }
```

Comment: What exactly are you not able to get in dataweave? the sequence or this JSON format (which is actually an ndjson  and not json array as you have mentioned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try iterating `(n - 1)` times where n is totalCount/splitNumber i.e. 9 times

If you are expecting in json array format then try with changing output type to `application/json`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/x-ndjson
var totalCount=1000 
var splitNumber=100
---
0 to ((totalCount/splitNumber)-1) map(item,index)->{
        "start": (splitNumber * item) + 1,
        "end": (item + 1) * splitNumber
}
```